# Diagnosing an erratic fan issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, fan

I am running Ubuntu 17 on a Dell XPS 9560, purchased brand-new last September. Last week I suddenly began having issues with the laptop fan:

- it randomly spins up at least every 15 minutes or so to 5000 or 6000 RPM, even when the CPU is idling and cool (see `sensors` report below)
- during those 5/6k periods, it will occasionally spin down to <2000 RPM for less than a second, then return to 5/6k

I currently have `i8kutils` installed to control the laptop fan, running with the default configuration file (which specifies that the fan should be at minimum speed when the CPU is below 50 C). Something else seems to be causing the fan to run like this..

I'm inclined to think this is actually a software / driver issue, but I'm not sure how to diagnose further. Here's why:

- The fan issues began on the same day that I upgraded my `nvidia-390` drivers.
- I promptly downgraded to the previous driver version, which made the fan problem go away for a few days.
- For some reason, though, the issues have now returned. (The drivers are still at their downgraded versions.)

Assuming this is a software problem — **how can I further diagnose which processes** might be making my fan go crazy? Is there any way to monitor which processes are setting fan speed?

(I'm also open to the suggestion that this must be a hardware problem, and that I should open up my laptop case instead!)

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

---

Here is the output from `sensors` while the fan is running near top speed:

```
$ sensors
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +32.5°C

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 6058 RPM
Video Fan:        0 RPM
CPU:            +34.0°C
Ambient:        +26.0°C
Ambient:        +27.0°C
Other:          +25.0°C

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Here's the `sensors` output a few moments later, when the fan is completely off with a *higher CPU temperature*:

```
$ sensors
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +36.5°C

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan:    0 RPM
Video Fan:        0 RPM
CPU:            +35.0°C
Ambient:        +29.0°C
Ambient:        +29.0°C
Other:          +29.0°C

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: If it helps, I can hear what sounds like a lot of rapid SSD reads (quiet ticking noises) when the fan first spins up, or is oscillating between high and low RPMs.

Comment: A similar issue (fan constantly on) appeared this morning when I updated ubuntu (18.04). Changing drivers to x.org makes the computer freeze. I also tried `nvidia-driver-396` with similar results.

Comment: FWIW: Looks like this was actually a hardware issue. I sent the laptop to Dell for repairs and with a new fan I have no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the inverse problem on an laptop, the fan was not running enough and got CPU crashes.

I've wrote a little script in order to help managing the fan rotation speed with more parameters in order to make it work following your own strategy.

To install it :

```
sudo npm install -g ubuntu-smart-fan
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect
```

After installing it, you can run it with default parameters :

```
sudo ubuntu-smart-fan --min=50
```

You can define your own strategy, take a look at the documentation here : https://github.com/ichiriac/ubuntu-smart-fan